# WebDriver - wait until invisibility of element

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

i have element defined in page page factory

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//*[contains(@style,'gxt/images/default/tree/loading.gif')]")
WebElement treeLoading;
```

i would like to wait for this element to disappear and ExpectedConditions does not support invisiblityOfElementLocated(WebElement), is there any better approach to write custom wait?

Answer (score 1):

so, finally i came with following solution using fluent wait

```
protected void waitUntilElementDisappear(final WebElement element){
        try{
              new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
              .withTimeout(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
              .pollingEvery(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
              .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class)
              .until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>(){
                public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver){
                    return (!element.isDisplayed());                             
                }
              }
            );
        }catch(TimeoutException e){
            fail("Time Out On : "+element);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's annoying that pagefactory page objects don't work with ExpectedConditions.

I use a custom wait method (C#/NUnit) it should be easy to convert to Java:

```
    public void WaitUntilNotVisible(IWebElement pageObject)
    {
        for (int second = 0; ; second++)
        {
            if (second >= 15) Assert.Fail("Error: Element still visible");
            try
            {
                if (!pageObject.Displayed) break;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            { }
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
```

This method works where a web element is hidden but still present. If you want  to wait until the element is no longer present then you need to catch a NoSuchElementException to break the loop.