# How to handle Calendar that is overlapping with other elements in Selenium automation using Java?

Tags: java, selenium, automation, calendar, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to implement the following scenario
1. Open Chrome browser and open greyhound.com
2. Search a trip by picking a source, destination.
3. Pick a start date, return date.
4. Finally, click on search button to find available buses.

First four fields work fine. After picking the return date, the calendar won't close, which is causing a problem for clicking the search button.
The calendar is overlapping with the search button and makes it non-clickable.

To overcome this, I have used Thread.sleep() to allow some time for the calendar to close and it works fine.
How can I achieve this using selenium wait concept?
Both implicit and explicit waits won't work for me.

```
    public class UsingChrome {
        public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {

            //Chrome Driver
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "Y:\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe");

            //Creating driver element
            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

            //Implicit Wait
            //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            //To maximize browser window
            driver.manage().window().maximize();

            //Open webpage
            driver.get("https://www.greyhound.com/");

            //Scroll
            JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
            jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,300)", "");

            //Select an origin and destination
            driver.findElement(By.id("fromLocation")).sendKeys("New York, NY");
            driver.findElement(By.id("toLocation")).sendKeys("Boston, MA");

            // To input a date using 'sendKeys'
            //Choose a Start Date
            driver.findElement(By.id("datepicker-from")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.id("datepicker-from")).sendKeys("10/22/2017");

            //Choose an End Date
            driver.findElement(By.id("datepicker-to")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.id("datepicker-to")).sendKeys("10/27/2017");
            driver.findElement(By.id("datepicker-to")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);


            //Explicit wait
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 300);
            WebElement search = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id=\'fare-search-btn\']")));
            search.click();

            //Search
            //Thread.sleep(3000);
            driver.findElement(By.id("fare-search-btn")).click();

            //driver.quit();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you need to wait for the return trip datepicker to close. The return trip datepicker element is

```
<table class="ui-datepicker-calendar">...</table>
```

The code to wait for it to close is to wait for the element to be invisible.

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("table.ui-datepicker-calendar")));
```

Your code was waiting for the Search button to be visible. Technically it's already visible, it's just covered by the datepicker dropdown. Visibility in Selenium has to do with not invisible (display: none, etc.) rather than I can't see it because it's covered by another element.

Comment: Above solution provided by @JeffC will work , you can improvise the above code using fluent wait. check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28224943/webdriver-wait-until-invisibility-of-element)

Comment: @richardmendonca `FluentWait` is just a fully customizable version of `WebDriverWait`. There's no need for it here since the code above will do what OP needs.

Comment: @JeffC That invisibility of element you used worked. Thanks!

Comment: @JeffC , agreed what you mentioned, but as stated in my previous comment you can "improvise  the code with FluentWait".Because fluent wait provide's you to take advantage of pooling ,finally it will be decisions of developer how he/she fits in the code.As there are always different  approach to solve a problem . Cheers !!

Comment: @richardmendonca You stated, "take advantage of pooling", but I think you meant "polling." Polling is when every 500ms (or whatever time is set) another attempt to check the condition is made. Polling is done every 500ms with `WebDriverWait` also. I would suggest you do some reading on `WebDriverWait` and `FluentWait` to better understand how they work and how they are similar and different.